# What happens to the memory not used in a big dynamic array?

Tags: c, dynamic-memory-allocation, dynamic-arrays

Consider the following lines of code:

```
char* f = (char *)(malloc(10240 * sizeof(char)));
scanf(%s, f);
```

Now when the input is a string with any no. of characters less than 10240, what happens to the rest of the memory in this dynamic array?

What if I want to remove an element of this dynamic array without changing the size of this dynamic array, how do I do that?

Comment: nothing will happen with the rest of array

Comment: i mean does it remain empty?

Comment: it does remain the same (ie garbage from previous apps)

Comment: `malloc` doesn't initialize the allocated memory blocks.  So, it will have whatever happened to be in those locations before.  `scanf` won't touch any memory location beyond to length of the input string.

Comment: What does your C book state? Why do you think you have a problem? Why would dynamically allocated arrays behave different than automatic or static arrays? Note: you cannot **remove** an element from an array.

Comment: remove element == change size usually

Comment: @kartikeykant18 Not sure what you mean by "empty". The bytes after `scanf()` terminates it with a null byte remain uninitialized.

Answer (score 1):

What happens to a 5-gallon bucket when you only put a cup of water in it?  It's still a 5-gallon bucket, it just sits there mostly empty. If you want to reclaim the space for other use, you can do the equivalent of pouring the water into a smaller cup and returning the bucket (i.e., allocate a new chunk of memory just big enough for your string, copy the string over, then `free()` the big block), or use `realloc()` to magically shrink the bucket.

Answer (score 0):

> Now when the input is a string with any no. of characters less than 10240, what happens to the rest of the memory in this dynamic array?

Nothing happens. It's available for you to use but you don't need to use it or do anything about.